# Reading HTML Text File from HDD is Showing No Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, file-handling

My bot visits a website, downloads its view-source, and stores it to a text file (C:\ViperBot\GOW\trooptable.txt). I have checked the file and it looks great.  It then creates a custom personal file that I will use later. The next step is to read the text file and start searching for the information I want to find and relay the information to the user.

I have tried every single line-by-line file reader and every one of them shows no results whether I use message.channel.send or console.log.  All of the other file-handling methods are working except for when it's time to read the file. Something must be missing and I Don't know what.

```
    else if (command === 'troop' || command === 'trp') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You must specify a search criteria.\nExample; To search for Abhorath:\n.troop abhorath\n.trp abh`);
        }
        let i = 0;
        let crit = '';

        for (i = 0; i < args.length; crit += args[i] + ' ', i++) {
        }

        crit = crit.slice(0, crit.length - 1);

        message.channel.send(`I got your troop request for ${crit}.`);


        message.channel.send('Parsing...');

        let file = fs.createWriteStream("C:/ViperBot/GOW/trooptable.txt");
        let request = http.get("http://gowdb.com/trooptable", function (response) {
            response.pipe(file);
        });

        message.channel.send('Finished');
        fs.writeFile(`C:/ViperBot/GOW/tmp${message.author.username}.txt`, 'Michael Luna', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
        message.channel.send(`File created: tmp${message.author.username}.txt`);

        var stream = fs.createReadStream('C:/ViperBot/GOW/trooptable.txt');
        stream = byline.createStream(stream);

        stream.on('readable', function() {
            var line;
            while (null !== (line = stream.read())) {
                message.channel.send(line);
                message.channel.send('Is anything happening?');
            }
        });

    }
```

This last method is using a module called byline.  All of the comments say that it works beautifully. I have used every single line-by-line I found and they all produce no results.

All I can think of is that there's something I'm not doing. The console shows no errors. The bot doesn't stop. It just returns no output and goes right back to waiting for chat input.

```
message.channel.send('Is anything happening?');
```

I put the above code in just to see if it would say it, and it doesn't. So something is computing that there are no lines to read.

The first line of the text file isn't blank. It's formatted exactly like it would look if you did a view-source on a browser.

Comment: I didn't think about trying this code out on other text files. The code works fine. The only problem is that it doesn't work on a text file as big as the one I was trying to use, even streaming, for whatever reason, wouldn't work in that big of a file. It's surprising that it would be this difficult to get something so simple done.

Comment: I compiled a QuickBASIC program to extract all the data I needed and wrote a smaller text file for JS to read. It's a shame that I had to use an out-dated DOS program to do the job a program created decades later can't handle properly.